# Getting out of while loops

Tags: java, do-while

I am writing a program in java where the user inputs grades [A, B, C, D, F]. They cannot mention the number of classes so how do I get out of the while loop after they are done.

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter your grades for all the subjects: ");
  String sub1 = input.nextLine();
}
while (<condition>);
```

I want to understand what kind of *<condition>* I could use?

Comment: how about asking them to enter a `Q` to quit?

Comment: Ohhh ya I think that works Thanks.

Comment: Could even follow that up with an "Are you sure you want to quit? (Y/N)" prompt to avoid typos with entering As

Comment: Or empty line (`!sub1.isEmpty()` as condition)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; how about asking them to enter a Q to quit?

## Foreword

This answer is *highly* opinionated, and as such

1. it's not exhaustive in nature, and therefore not deterministic.
2. not really in line with SO policy to avoid opinionated answers

I chose to give an opinionated answer in this case because beginner programmers struggle with some of the topics I'll touch on, and hopefully this answer will act as a guide.

The exploration below is intended to give you (the OP) a way to explore solutions about the problem presented and to hopefully expand your understanding on how to attack software design and software development in the future.

## Preamble

We start with an assumption (oh the irony) that your original problem-statement probably went something like:

> Write a program that accepts grades from a user and then ... *do something with it*, e.g. *compute the overall/average grade of the user*

While there are explicit requirements defined by the problem-statement, there are many implicit requirements as well that you, as a software designer, have to make and then use them to create your software.

And because, they are not explicitly defined, they (largely) are up to you to figure out become (aesthetic?) design choices made by you.

So let's just dive right in :-)

## Our (first) solution

Let's start with where we're at. We make a few assumptions to pin down our design and therefore our program:

- ASSUMPTION: Our user to enter her grades **one grade at a time**
- ASSUMPTION: She wants her result once she's done entering the grades

In the second assumption there's an implicit assumption that she'll be indicating that she's done entering the grades.

In this case our steps could go something like:

```
DO 
     INPUT GRADE OR DONE INDICATOR
     IF DONE 
          BREAK OUT OF LOOP
     END IF
     STORE GRADE 
LOOP

CALCULATE AVERAGE
SHOW RESULTS
```

## A different solution

However, we could've made different assumptions:

- ASSUMPTION: Our user wants to enter her grades one at a time
- ASSUMPTION: She wants to see a running average
- ASSUMPTION: She doesn't care about getting done, but perhaps wants to reset the average instead along the way

Now our program may look like:

```
DO 
     ASK FOR A GRADE OR RESET
     IF RESET 
        RESET THE AVERAGE
     ELSE
        ADD GRADE TO CALCULATED AVERAGE
     END IF
     DISPLAY AVERAGE         
LOOP
```

### On the solutions above

As you can see we ended up making plenty of assumptions about the problem to try and pin down what the user wants to experience from our software.

There was another rather blatant assumption that we made which was implicit as well that is that our **`PROCESS GRADE`** step is very well defined and the user we are able to simply program that in without the user's input on it.

## Even more directions (Choices, Choices, Choices)

And then there are assumptions and directions we could've taken that are completely different from the ones above. Some examples to consider:

- She wants something that looks like a calculator
- She expects to enter grades in batches

  - may be of different sizes
  - may be of IDENTICAL sizes
- She expects to give parameters on how to calculate the result (weighted averages?)
- May be because she's going to process 100,000,000 grades

## Narrowing it down

So, how do we pick which one? Well there are many valid answers to this question as well.

When trying to figure out what design approach you're going to take, consider these mostly nontechnical (common-sense??) factors:

- Expectation of the user

  - Look at how users use similar programs, what do they expect?
  - When in doubt, ask the users
  - However, remember the old adage,

    > "If you make a program that even a fool can use, only a fool will use it"
- Ease of programming

  - Is your approach too complicated for a given problem?
  - Will you be able to understand your design choices 6 months from now (if you didn't document them -- baaad idea, but still)
- Does anybody (including you) care?

  - Make something, usually if you keep it simple no one will care about the assumptions you made

As you can see, this is highly subjective, and you as a software designer have a lot of power (and per Uncle Ben) therefore a lot of responsibility, to make sane choices for your user and for yourself.

## Concluding remarks

All of my thoughts above are meant to help you open your mind to start thinking about set of values and principles for software development. You can create your own, or adopt one of the existing ones and make that your own.  I would suggest, at least looking at some software development approaches that are already out there which address some of the topics I touched upon. Even if you don't understand all the technical nitty gritty, just having a 50,000 foot view of them will help you in your endeavors

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development
- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns--net-12752

And follow the web rabbit hole.

Bon-chance young padawan and happy coding :-)

Comment: That doesn't look like an answer instead a comment

Comment: You're right, it is phrased like a comment. I'll elaborate

Answer (score 1):

A common way of doing it is to press `crtl-d` on mac/unix systems / `ctrl-z` on windows when you're done.
If that fits your need, you can do it this way:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter your grades for all the subjects: ");
    String text = new String(scanner.nextLine());
    //... do what you want here ...
} while (scanner.hasNextLine());
scanner.close();
```